# If atmospheric pressure causes an increase in a fluids pressure, wouldn't attaching a piezometer to a pipe cause the change in fluid pressure inside?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, fluid-statics

So say I've got a pipe, and it's got some kind of an internal pressure. Now, it's completely enclosed, so atmospheric pressure cannot affect it. Then, if I wanted to measure the pipe's pressure by drilling a hole and attaching a piezometric tube, like in the picture, wouldn't I be providing an entrance to the atmospheric pressure, and thus the pressure inside the pipe would increase accordingly, according to the Pascal's law, which states that any increase in a fluid's pressure (pipe's contents are affected through the piezo tube) is transmitted undiminished? So the actual pressure inside the tube, P, would become P+Pa, which would mean to get the actual pressure we'd have to subtract Pa?

I know I'm not making much sense here, but imagine a container with fluid in it. If we opened the container and allowed the fluid's surface to be in contact with it, the atmospheric pressure would increase the amount of pressure already present in the liquid,so the total pressure would be higher for Pa.

[image]

Comment: In engineering, there are two commonly used pressure measurements.  Absolute pressure is a measure of total pressure, including atmospheric pressure.  Gauge pressure is a measure of the pressure above atmospheric pressure.  When a pressure measurement or specification is stated, it is explicitly stated whether the pressure is gauge or absolute.

Answer (score 0):

First a little background. Many atomic bonds are a little like very stiff springs. They hold two atoms a fixed distance apart. If you pull on the atoms, they stretch slightly and pull the atoms toward each other.

You make a tube out of atoms. If you try to fit slightly more fluid in the tube than can fit, you stretch the tube. The bonds try to stay at their preferred length. They try to reduce the volume of the tube, which compresses the fluid. This is how the pressure is maintained.

For water in a metal tubke, the stretching and compressing is so slight as to be unnoticeable unless the forces are extreme. We usually say that fluids like water are incompressible.

Some bonds do allow easy stretching. For example, rubber is made of long chains like a sawtooth. It is stretchy because the angles can bend. If you pressurize a rubber tube, you would expand it and it would hold more water.

Suppose you cut a hole in the pressurized tube. A patch that was exerting an inward force on the water is now missing. Water flows out of the hole, the tube contracts, and pressure inside drops to atmospheric pressure.

Now you add a piezometer. You fill it with water up to a certain level. The water in the piezometer exerts a force on the water in the tube. Pressure in the tube increases. Water pushes on the inner surface of the tube, expanding it. The tube's bonds cause the tube to resist the expansion, pressing on the water. It is now just like it was before you cut the hole. Force from water in the piezometer has replaced the force from the missing patch of tube.

---

So how does air pressure influence this?

Suppose you have a metal tube that is so strong air pressing on the outside has little influence on the inside. Air pressure still adds to the force exerted by the piezometer. If there was a vacuum outside, you would have to add fluid to a higher level to produce the same force and the pressure in the tube.

Suppose you had a rubber tube. Air pressing on the outside of the tube helps the tube pressurize the water inside. If there was vacuum outside, the pressure inside would be less. So you would not need the additional force from air on the end of the piezometer to balance the forces. If you start with air outside and pump it away to vacuum, the level in the piezometer would not change.

---

We often ignore air pressure. We might think of the tube with a hole in it as unpressurized, as having pressure $0$. In reality, the pressure is $1$ atmosphere.

It is a little like asking how much a big plastic trash bag full of water weighs. Normally you would say hundreds of pounds. But if you were holding it under water, it would be weightless.

It can be confusing unless everyone is careful to agree on whether or not to ignore atmospheric pressure.